# Would a NAS and a PC have a gigabit connection if connected through a gigabit switch?

Tags: switch, router

I have a gigabit enabled NAS and a non-gigabit router at the moment. If I connected both the PC and the NAS into the gigabit switch, then connected the switch into the router, would the PC and the NAS have gigabit connection through each other? Im not bothered too much not having gigabit speeds coming from the router since I only have 50 mbps internet anyway.

My NAS is a WD MyCloud and has its interface and takes an IP from the router so Im not sure if a switch would work. Will it work?

Comment: Sadly, home networking questions are off topic here. You can consider asking this on [su].

Comment: @TeunVink Its fine, Daniel already gave me a good answer. Should I delete this, or could you delete this?

Comment: It's closed, to no need to delete it anymore.

Comment: @Teun, since it got an upvoted answer, deletion or migration are most appropriate.  The system will not auto-delete questions with upvoted answers

Comment: The speed limit is always determined by the slowest component in the chain.  For older computers it can be the CPU, even.   But with a gigabit router and 100mbps Ethernet cards, the max would be 100 mbps.  You can get faster throughput via WiFi, for very reasonable cost.  But if you are Giga from end to end then you beat any kind of normal WiFi hands down.   @Daniel is right on, and rightfully accepted.

Comment: Deleting this would have been a shame.  I just ran across it 1 year and 10 months after it was first posted.  It was worth finding.  This is a database and the more information the better, especially when the titles are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speed of the Ethernet is determined by the Layer 1 of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) whereas the IP is Layer 3, so the IP will not have any influence on the Ethernet network speed.

Said that, in your setup, if NAS and the PC have both Gigabit NICs and they are both connected to different ports of the same Gigabit Switch using at least [Cat 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) cables, they will communicate at Gigabit speed.

Comment: Great, and one more thing, devices not connected to the switch but is connected to the router would still be able to access the NAS, right? Only not in gigabit speeds?

Comment: Exactly. They will all be in the same "network segment". Just keep in mind that most of the SOHO routers, have 4 ports labeled as LAN that are actually behaving as a Switch. The "router" part is what connect this 4 ports to the Internet (ADSL, FO, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

If the NAS and the PC are in the same subnet then they should be in the same VLAN so no routing will be used.  So, just check that both have IP addresses in the same subnet and if they do then you should have a gigabit connection between the two devices.